Why would SMHI's weather API have this scaling for cloud coverage?
SMHI´s API have the below documentation for its properties. What intrigued me is the value range (0-8) for 'tcc_mean'.
Not only does it differ from other properties on the API, for example humidity that has a range of 0-100. It also do not map, what I imagine, strait to 0-100%. Let me explain:



cloud cover
mapped to percent




0
0-10%


1
10-20%


...
...


7
70-80%


8
80-90%



100% cloud coverage can not happen? Great Britain would like a word!
Question:
So why did SMHI choose this scale? I'm sure the engineers are way smarter then me. So the answer eludes me . My first guess is that a scale 0-8 indicates a lower precision than 0-100, but that does not really answer the mapping problem to percent.



Parameter
Unit
Level Type
Level (m)
Description
Value range




msl
hPa
hmsl
0
Air pressure
Decimal number, one decimal


t
C
hl
2
Air temperature
Decimal number, one decimal


vis
km
hl
2
Horizontal visibility
Decimal number, one decimal


wd
degree
hl
10
Wind direction
Integer


ws
m/s
hl
10
Wind speed
Decimal number, one decimal


r
%
hl
2
Relative humidity
Integer, 0-100


tstm
%
hl
0
Thunder probability
Integer, 0-100


tcc_mean
octas
hl
0
Mean value of total cloud cover
Integer, 0-8


...
...
...
...
...
...




This is not answerable unless you work for SMHI, and furthermore unless you were one of the developers who implemented that particular part of the API. Questions like this typically get closed as being opinion-based, because only personnel at the company can answer it.

I am sure the engineers at SMHI (and other Meteorological entities) are really clever and it is NOT by chance they choose this scale. I would argue this is not opinion-based, but rather based on technical expertice and deep knowledge about the subject. Hence: my question do have a fact-based answer.

But none of us work at the company, therefore any answer we provide is pure conjecture. You are also making some big assumptions about there being some industry convention or meteorological formula for this. A programmer might have declared an enum and their programming framework serializes that enum as a number. But again, we are just guessing.

@GregBurghardt.  To clarify: Indeed, asking a employee would yield an answer. But the question can be answered nonetheless. An organization and API of this magnitude does not leave decisions like this up to chance. It is fact based. Hence, it can be answered by anyone who has that knowledge.

I actually discovered the answer while arguing with @GregBurghardt in the comments. No hard feelings at all Greg. instead I thank you for making me discover a detail I overlooked. If we look at the unit for that property, it says 'octas'. I googled it and Wikipedia pretty much in the first sentence answer my question!

No offense taken. Care to post an answer?

The answer can be found in the unit, okta. Wikipedia does provide a detailed answer, so I will just include a breif summary of oktas.
Wikipedia about octas.

In meteorology, an okta is a unit of measurement used to describe the
amount of cloud cover at any given location such as a weather station.
Sky conditions are estimated in terms of how many eighths of the sky
are covered in cloud, ranging from 0 oktas (completely clear sky)
through to 8 oktas (completely overcast). In addition, in the SYNOP
code there is an extra cloud cover indicator '9' indicating that the
sky is totally obscured (i.e. hidden from view), usually due to dense
fog or heavy snow.2



Very nice! In fact, I would never have caught the key detail: the unit of measurement is "okta". (btw, +1)
